# Changing the default filename when using mPDF

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I'm currently using [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) to generate a pdf from HTML (which was generated by PHP).

All works as expected but I'd like to be able to change the default filename.  Currently, I have:

```
$payStub=new mPDF();
$payStub->SetTitle('My title');
$payStub->WriteHTML($pcTableRows);
$payStub->Output();
```

When I save the pdf that opened in my browser it defaults to `mpdf.pdf`.
Is it possible to change `mpdf.pdf` to something of my choosing?

I tried

```
$payStub->Output('myFileName.pdf');
```

and

```
$payStub->Output('myFileName.pdf', 'F');
```

but those want to save it to the server, I'm trying to have it for when the user saves it locally.

Comment: I am not familiar with the script but if it's written good, then try to change the filename of the "mpdf.pdf".

Comment: @FiratAkandere Tried that, no luck :-(

Comment: I just checked the manual and it seems that $payStub->Output('myFileName.pdf'); should do the job. Check it again with your cache is cleared.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try the `I` flag in the `Output` function, which will output the PDF to the browser, and use the filename from the first argument:

```
$payStub=new mPDF();
$payStub->SetTitle('My title');
$payStub->WriteHTML($pcTableRows);
$payStub->Output('yourFileName.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 23):

You can try as:

```
$file_name = 'yourFileName.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($file_name, 'D');
```

Help:

1. 'D': download the PDF file
2. 'I': serves in-line to the browser
3. 'S': returns the PDF document as a string
4. 'F': save as file $file_out

Comment: Also mPDF supports 4 constants for them in Destination class. \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE ('F'), \Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD ('D'), \Mpdf\Output\Destination::STRING_RETURN ('S'), \Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE ('I')

Answer (score -6):

Modify `mdpdf.php`

```
form.setAttribute("action", "'._MPDF_URI.'includes/out.php/'.$name.'");
```

for downloading with other name