# mPDF only getting "Finished" when progressBar enabled

Tags: php, progress-bar, mpdf

I'm generating a very large pdf file on my PHP application. The document can reach over **300 pages**. The build process may take more than `40 seconds`, that's why I want to show the user a message to understand that the file is being generated.

The problem is that when i set `$this->progressBar = 1;` on `config.php` file, the progress shows perfect, but when the proces finish, I'm only getting a **Finished** message, and i'm not redirected to the file.

Heres' my code:

```
 <?php

    ob_start(); 
include('include/mpdf/mpdf.php');
define('_MPDF_URI','../');
$mpdf = new mPDF('','A4', 9, 'freesans', 10, 10, 20, 15, 5, 5, 'L');
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($cabecera);
$mpdf->setFooter("Pagina {PAGENO} de {nb}");
$html=utf8_encode($html);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
ob_end_flush();
```

I believe someone already has gone through this problem. Please guide me on how I can solve this problem.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/startprogressbaroutput.html) has a note:

> **Note:** You may need to define the constant _MPDF_URI if you use progress bars. The constant _MPDF_URI is needed to redirect the user
>   to the PDF file (and prior to mPDF 5.0 to locate a javascript file
>   within the progress bar script). It must be either a relative path
>   (e.g. '../') or a full URI (e.g. 'http://www.example.com/mpdf/'). If
>   you do not define it before calling mPDF() mPDF will assign it the
>   same value as _MPDF_PATH. This is fine if you have used a relative
>   path. _MPDF_PATH requires either a relative path or a filesystem real
>   path (e.g. '/homepages/27/d84233457/htdocs/')

Then make sure the `->Output()` function has the correct parameters, such as:

```
$mpdf->Output('yourFileName.pdf', 'I');
```

For more info see [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688573).

Comment: yes, that was the first thing I tried. but then it away because it did not work. i just edited the question.

Comment: there is no error. the process finish correctly, but ir won't redirect to the file

Comment: Sorry, i'm getting this on the google chrome console:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/cl25demayo/include/mpdf/progbar.css

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/cl25demayo/include/mpdf/includes/out.php

Comment: Hi, you double check the _MPDF_URI?, it should be a valid URL or a valid relative url, not a system path, your problem is clasic when the _MPDF_URI is not set correctly, it generate the pdf but can't redirect because the URI does not exist

Comment: yes, I've checked at all. now I managed to redirect the PDF, but it opens named "out.php" then, if the user downloads it, the file downloads as "out.php"

Comment: I've updated my answer - check the `Output()` method.

Comment: I have already tried, but it is not the solution, since the default values ​​are "mpdf.pdf" and "I".
Looks like this is an issue of mpdf when using progress bar...